# Adding AVPlayerLayer as a sublayer doesn't fill parent view fully

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a cell containing a full width `UIImageView`, and I am creating an `AVPlayerLayer` to play an inline video. This works almost perfectly, the only problem being that when it is added to the `previewImage` image view, which is a full width image view which displays perfectly, it has a 1 px gap down the left side and the right side. So when the video is playing, you can really notice it and it's quite jarring.

I am setting it up like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! GameMediaCell

    if (cell.playerLayer != nil) {
        cell.playerLayer?.player?.pause()
        cell.playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        cell.playerLayer = nil

    } else {
        if let clipURI = viewModel?.mediaURIForIndex(indexPath.row) {

            let player = AVPlayer(url: clipURI)
            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

            playerLayer.frame = cell.previewImage.frame

            cell.previewImage.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            cell.playerLayer = playerLayer

            playerLayer.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this line before adding player layer as subview.

self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

Comment: I found this the other day somewhere, and it's the correct answer. Should have answered my own question, so I'll accept this. Thanks man :)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
//MARK: Add a new variable to your class where you are using AVPLayer  
let screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

//MARK:Than just create a new frame of AVPLayerLayer
self.avPlayerLayer!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.screenRect.size.width, self.screenRect.size.height)
```

Comment: this will work when you have a fullscreen player only